# Get this week's data using SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, date

I am trying to get this week's data in sqlite but it seems that I have missed something as i get wrong information back. To be more specific i want to retrieve all the data in my database that have a timestamp which its date falls in this week. This week may either start from Sunday or Monday i.e 26/2/12-03/03/12. At the moment I am using something like this: `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE DATE(timeStamp) == DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days')`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you should be pretty close. If you want everything since the start of this week, just a slight modification:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE DATE(timeStamp) >= DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days');
```

Comment: what's the difference if we say > or >= ?

Comment: Sorry about that. You're right, >= is probably the way to go as you'll want to catch records where the timeStamp is exactly equal to DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days').

Comment: Using > will treat Monday as the first day of the week while using >= will treat Sunday as the first day of the week. You should be good using either one depending on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

just change the format of date
 from this 26/02/12 to this 26-02-12
 for example set date format something like this in your editText

```
 editText.setText(year+"-"+month+"-"+day);
```