# How do I get this week's data?

Tags: sql, objective-c, sqlite, date, datetime

I am trying to code a method that will return the sum of all costs in my table "Cost" but in this current week (taking Monday as 1st day week)

This is how my DB looks like :

[image]

And this is the data I have inside

[image]

I have something like this :

```
- (float)getthisweekscosts {
    float sumprice = 0; // We initialize the total price for all the rows

    NSString *getcurrentcost = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"SELECT COSTAMOUNT FROM COST WHERE DATE > DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days')"];
    const char *query_stmt_budget = [getcurrentcost UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(costDB,query_stmt_budget, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW){
            NSString *currentcost = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            sumprice += [currentcost floatValue];
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }

    sqlite3_close(costDB);

    return sumprice;
}
```

Source : [Get this week's data using SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487835/get-this-weeks-data-using-sqlite)

But I am not sure why it returns 0 in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check COSTDATE column type DATE'?

if it's true,you don't need `DATE(COSTDATE)`

use `COSTDATE`

---

your data and sql is right

this is test demo

```
CREATE TABLE COST(
    COSTAMOUNT  REAL,
    COSTDATE DATE
);

INSERT INTO COST VALUES (2.48,'2018/05/19');
INSERT INTO COST VALUES (2.85,'2018/05/19');
INSERT INTO COST VALUES (null,null);


SELECT sum(COSTAMOUNT) --result 5.33
FROM COST 
WHERE COSTDATE > DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ac686/4/0)

---

debug and check your code

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(costDB,query_stmt_budget, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){

while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW){

    NSString *currentcost = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
    sumprice += [currentcost floatValue];
}
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

Comment: I uploaded a picture of how my DB looks like. COSTDATE is well defined and I have used just `COSDATE` instead of `DATE(COSTDATE)`. No luck :(

Comment: I did ! Now I have it like this : `WHERE DATE > DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days')` but I still get 0.

Comment: SELECT sum(COSTAMOUNT) FROM COST WHERE COSTDATE > DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days')

try it,if still 0 ,please show your data

Comment: SELECT COSTAMOUNT,COSTDATE  FROM T 
order by COSTDATE  desc ,use this script show your top 10 data

Comment: I uploaded a picture with the data I have. They are just a few records

Comment: Its nice that you created the SQL Fiddle. If I add this line `INSERT INTO COST VALUES (1.00,'2018/04/12');` ( which is last week) , the result is 6,33 :( . I really don't know what can be wrong.

Comment: sql is right,try debug run your code,check your code's logic

Comment: check your db sysdate , select 
  DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days')
  ,DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-0 days')
;

Comment: I get "2018-05-13" for the first one and "2018-05-20" for the second one

Comment: it seems sql is right,do you debug check your code?

Comment: Yeah I actually have :(. When I run `SELECT sum(COSTAMOUNT) FROM COST` it gets me all rows. thats fine. But when I add the  `WHERE COSTDATE > DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days')` then I get 0 rows. So I am. sure 100% the problem is there :(